Uploading multiple files with React and Axios
I am trying to upload image with React/express.
While I am able to do with Postman, sent image with react is strange.
I try everything but I was not able to solve the issue for days.
What I get in express server from postman is (which works form me):
[Object: null prototype] {
  images: {
    name: 'Screenshot 2023-08-11 171018.png',
    data: <Buffer 89  ... 331059 more bytes>,
    size: 331109,
    encoding: '7bit',
    tempFilePath: '',
    truncated: false,
    mimetype: 'image/png',
    md5: '6be5bdc5634eb2db7642e278e1682b97',
    mv: [Function: mv]
  }
}

and from my react app:
[Object: null prototype] {
  'images[]': {
    name: 'WIN_20200608_07_06_22_Pro.jpg',
    data: <Buffer f0 ... 196388 more bytes>,
    size: 196438,
    encoding: '7bit',
    tempFilePath: '',
    truncated: false,
    mimetype: 'image/jpeg',
    md5: 'ba567ce8ff2e8b0b987f4088ca9a3306',
    mv: [Function: mv]
  }
}

Why the images array returned as string and not as a real object name or an array of object when the files are multiple?
reducer
 if (action.type === UPDATE_IMAGES_INFO) {
    return { ...state, images:action.payload };
  }

  if (action.type === CREATE_PRODUCT_BEGIN) {
    return {
      ...state,
      product_create_loading: true,
      product_create_error: false,
    };
  }

context
const initialState = {
  ...
  images: null,
};
 const updateImagesInfo = (event) => {
    const value = event.target.files;
    console.log(value);
    dispatch({ type: UPDATE_IMAGES_INFO, payload: value });
  };

  const createProduct =
    (title, company, category, subcategory, description, images) =>
    async (event) => {
      dispatch({ type: CREATE_PRODUCT_BEGIN });
      event.preventDefault();
      const data = {
       ...
        images,
      };
      console.log(data);
      try {
        const response = await axios.post(`${products_url}`, data, {
          withCredentials: true,
          headers: {
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
          },
        });
        const product = response.data.order;
        dispatch({ type: CREATE_PRODUCT_SUCCESS, payload: product });
      } catch (error) {
        dispatch({
          type: CREATE_PRODUCT_ERROR,
          payload: error.response.data.msg,
        });
      }
    };

createProductPage
<form
  className='md:col-span-2'
  method='POST'
  onSubmit={createProduct(
    title,
    company,
    category,
    subcategory,
    description,
    images
  )}>
            <label
              htmlFor='images'>
              <span>upload image</span>
              <input
                id='images'
                name='images'
                type='file'
                className='sr-only'
                onChange={updateImagesInfo}
                multiple
              />
            </label>
            <p>or drag and drop</p>
          </div>
          <p >PNG, JPG, GIF up to 10MB</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div >
    <button
      type='submit'>
      create product
    </button>
  </div>
</form>;

express.js
const images = req.files;


try using form data instead of json serialization, see: Submit multiple files in axios request as an object
